# Sorting Multi-Dimensional Array PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I've that proceed this array in PHP

```
array(
    "id" => 1,
    "name" => "Carlos"
    "other" => array("key" => "Hello")
),
array(
    "id" => 3,
    "name" => "Carlos" 
    "other" => array("key" => "Hello")
),
array(
    "id" => 2,
    "name" => "Carlos"
    "other" => array("key" => "Hello")
)
```

and I need to order by "id". I've try it using usort and many multidimensional solutions but doesn't work for me.

I used that:

```
$price = array();
foreach ($inventory as $key => $row)
{
    $price[$key] = $row['price'];
}
array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $inventory);
```

But doesn't work because my array has many dimentions.

```
$departamento = $this->Departamentos->get($id, [
        'contain' => [
            'Asignaturas.Mallas',
            'Asignaturas.Secciones.Perfiles',
            'Asignaturas.Secciones.Mallas.Carreras',
            'Unidades'
        ]
    ]);
```

That is my query in Cakephp. I need to order by Secciones.id

Comment: SHow the code you tried that didn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: @charlietfl is a result of a query from cakephp

Comment: @maazza that question is about two-dimentions array. My array is multidimentional

Comment: "That question is about two-dimentions array. My array is multidimentional." Yours can be sorted in the same way. Incidentally,  a 2-d array in php *is* multidimensional, strictly speaking.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang I know that. But, that answer only works in **2-d array**

Comment: Please write an answer, and accept it so the question is closed. Don't edit the question to say "solved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Hash::sort 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html

And works fine for me ;)